# How to get a 2D array to write from a file with only spaces used as separators

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I am attempting to take a file and put it into 3 different arrays. Two of these arrays are 1D arrays, and the other one is a 2D one. The text file is as follows

```
Bill Hansley 1 1 1 1 1
Todd Howard 2 3 1 0 0
Sam Duke 0 1 1 0 0
Danny Martin 1 0 2 0 1
```

I am trying to take this text file, and insert it the first names into an array called firstNames[], then another array for the last names called lastNames[], and finally for the numbers, I want them in an array called Productsorders[][]. My code is as follows.

```
bool loadOrderFile(string orderFN,
    string firstNames[], string lastNames[],
    int productsOrders[MAX_ORDERS][MAX_PRODS],
    int &namesCount, int &prodCount, string &menuName) 
{
    ifstream File;
    File.open(orderFN.c_str());
    if (File.is_open()) {
        cout << "Order file opened..." << endl;
    }
    int i = 0;
    getline(File, menuName);
    (File >> prodCount);
    while (File) {
        File.get();
        (File >> firstNames[i]);
        (File >> lastNames[i]);
        (File >> productsOrders[i][i]);
        (File >> productsOrders[i + 1][i + 1]);
        (File >> productsOrders[i + 2][i + 2]);
        (File >> productsOrders[i + 3][i + 3]);
        (File >> productsOrders[i + 4][i + 4]);

        (i++);
    }
    cout << "Menu name: " << menuName << endl;
    cout << "Product Count: " << prodCount << endl;
    cout << "There were " << (prodCount - 1) << " orders read in." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << productsOrders[i][i] << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << firstNames[i] << lastNames[i] << endl;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The name arrays seem to work as they output the names as it should but the 2D array outputs

```
1
2
0
1
0
2
0
1
0
0
```

when it should be

```
1 1 1 1 1
2 3 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 0
1 0 2 0 1
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: The information that you shown from the contents of your file; is there header information before the contents? Or does it start the file from what you've shown? I see that you have a `getline()` call for `menuName`, then an extraction from the file for `prodCount`, then finally inside of your while loop you have a `fstream::get()` call before you start to populate your arrays. Just trying to understand your file structure better to try and parse it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are not addressing your 2D arrays correctly here.

For example, in a `3x3` *2D array* you have two indexes `[a][b]`, a 2D representation of that array would look like this:

```
[0][0] [0][1] [0][2]

[1][0] [1][1] [1][2]

[2][0] [2][1] [2][2]
```

So when you were outputting for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout << productsOrders[i][i] << endl;
}
```

You can see that you would only be getting a diagonal line through the array rather than all of the items (`[0][0], [1][1], [2][2]`). To print the entire array you would need to use two loops.

You have a similar issue with your input where you are increasing both indexes simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly when parsing text files; I would separate the logic into individual functions according to their unique responsibilities.

You code would look something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream> 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <exception>

// Structure of your data type...
struct Order {
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    std::vector<int> productOrders; // maybe use vector instead of array...
    // any other variable(s) or container(s) you may need...
};

// Simple ostream operator<< overload to print your Order Struct
// in a nice readable format.
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Order& order ); 

// Function to split a string based on a single character delimiter
std::vector<std::string> splitString( const std::string& s, char delimiter );

// Function that will get each line text from a file and stores it into a vector
// of strings. Then closes the file handle once the entire file has been read.
void getAllLinesFromFile(const char* filename, std::vector<std::string>& output);

// This function will parse a single line of text or string that is contained in 
// the vector of strings. The declaration of this can vary; if you have other
// information such as header information before the actual data structures
// you would have to modify this function's declaration-definition to accommodate
// for those variables. 
void parseLine( const std::vector<std::string>& fileContents, std::vector<Order>& orders );

// Simple and clean looking main function.
int main() {
    try {
        std::vector<std::string> fileContents;
        getAllLinesFromFile( "filename.txt", fileContents );
        std::vector<Order> orders;
        parseLine( fileContents, orders );

        for ( auto& o : orders )
            std::cout << o << '\n';           

    } catch( std::runtime_error& e ) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Order& order ) {
    os << order.firstName << " " << order.lastName << '\n';    
    for (auto& p : order.productOrders)
        os << p << " ";
    os << '\n';
    return os;
}


std::vector<std::string> splitString( const std::string& s, char delimiter ) {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::string token;
    std::istringstream tokenStream( s );
    while( std::getline( tokenStream, token, delimiter ) ) {
        tokens.push_back( token );
    }

    return tokens;
}

void getAllLinesFromFile(const char* filename, std::vector<std::string>& output) {
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    if (!file) {
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << "failed to open file " << filename << '\n';
        throw std::runtime_error(stream.str());
    } else {
        std::cout << "File " << filename << " opened successfully.\n";
    }

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        if (line.size() > 0)
            output.push_back(line);
    }
    file.close();
}

void parseLine( const std::vector<std::string>& fileContents, std::vector<Order>& orders ) {
    // Here is where you would do the logic to parse the vector of strings
    // this function may vary based on your file structure. If there is any
    // header information you would have to extract that first from the 
    // vector's index. 

    // Once you get to the index in the vector that describes your data structure
    // it is hear that you would want to call `splitString()` using the current
    // current index of that vector and the space character as your delimiter.
    // This will create a vector of strings that are now considered to be tokens.

    // On each pass of the loop for each line of contents you will want to
    // create an instance of the Order Structure, then use that to populate
    // the vector of Orders that was passed in by reference.

    // Once all of the contents are done being parsed the function will exit
    // and your vector of Orders will have the appropriate data.    
}
```

Having this kind of structure would make it easier to debug when parsing text files. I believe that it is more elegant to retrieve all of the data from a file and store it into some container; the easiest to work with would be either a `string`, or some `stream buffer` such as `stringstream`. Then close the file when you are done getting all of the contents. After everything has been read from the text file and stored into a container of strings. This is where you would want to parse the `strings` or `streams`, and to check to see if the information is valid or not. Opening and closing a file handle many times is inefficient and slow, and much can go wrong. I think it's easier to get the contents from file, save it, close it and be done with the file, then move on to the actual work.